# `UndefVarError` in a Julia macro

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

To help my debugging (and also in order to better understand how Julia macros
work), I'm trying to define a simple macro that sourrounds blocks of code with
"Entering" and "Leaving" notifications. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
macro dbg(block_title, expr)
    quote
        title = $block_title
        println("Entering $title")
        $expr
        println("Leaving  $title")
    end
end
```

At first glance, it seems to do what I want:

```
julia> @dbg "first test" begin
           println("does it work?")
       end
Entering first test
does it work?
Leaving  first test
```

however, as soon as variables are involved, nothing works anymore and I get
`UndefVarError` for all variables accesses. It looks like
the scope inside and outside the macro are distinct:

```
julia> @dbg "initialization" begin
           foo = rand(10)
           println("foo = ", foo)
       end
Entering initialization
foo = [0.9178016919066918, 0.6004694971609528, 0.5294790810682284, 0.04208146400653634, 0.09271603217172952, 0.2809448815925, 0.68236281020963, 0.8313876607106496, 0.07484095574744898, 0.14099531301938573]
Leaving  initialization

julia> foo
ERROR: UndefVarError: foo not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In short, you're missing the notion of [macro
hygiene](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Hygiene-1) and
in particular the [`esc`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.esc)
function.

Although this part of the documentation is a good read for anyone wanting to develop their own macros, let's try to expand a little on what macro hygiene does in this particular example, and how you can fix things.

A useful way to debug macros is provided by
[`@macroexpand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@macroexpand):

```
julia> @macroexpand @dbg "initialization" begin
           foo = rand(10)
           println("foo = ", foo)
       end
quote
    #= REPL[1]:3 =#
    var"#32#title" = "initialization"
    #= REPL[1]:4 =#
    Main.println("Entering $(var"#32#title")")
    #= REPL[1]:5 =#
    begin
        #= REPL[5]:2 =#
        var"#33#foo" = Main.rand(10)
        #= REPL[5]:3 =#
        Main.println("foo = ", var"#33#foo")
    end
    #= REPL[1]:6 =#
    Main.println("Leaving  $(var"#32#title")")
end
```

Leaving aside all comments within `#= ... =#` markers, we see almost the code we
wanted to get: the user code block has been surrounded with statements printing
the "Entering" and "Leaving" notifications. However, there is one notable
difference: variable names like `foo` or `title` have been
replaced with weirdly looking names like `var"#33#foo"` or `var"#32#title"`. This is what is called
"[macro hygiene](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Hygiene-1)", and it helps avoiding clashes that could occur between the
variables used in the macro itself (like `title` in this example), and the variables used in the code block
provided as an argument to the macro (like `foo` here). (Think for example what
would happen if you used you `@dbg` on a code block that defines a `title` variable.)

Julia errs on the side of caution, and protects in this way all variables
appearing in the macro. If you want to disable this for selected parts of the
expression produced by the macro, you can wrap these subexpressions inside the
[`esc`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.esc)
function. In your example, you should for example escape the user-provided
expression:

```
macro dbg(block_title, expr)
    quote
        title = $block_title
        println("Entering $title")
        $(esc(expr))
        println("Leaving  $title")
    end
end
```

Now things should work like want them to:

```
julia> @dbg "initialization" begin
           foo = rand(10)
           println("foo = ", foo)
       end
Entering initialization
foo = [0.2955287439482881, 0.8989053281359838, 0.27751430906108343, 0.4920810199867245, 0.7633806735297282, 0.34535540650110597, 0.7099231627594489, 0.39978144801175564, 0.9104888704503833, 0.1983996781283539]
Leaving  initialization

julia> @dbg "computation" begin
           foo .+= 1
       end
Entering computation
Leaving  computation

julia> foo
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.295528743948288 
 1.8989053281359838
 1.2775143090610834
 1.4920810199867245
 1.7633806735297282
 1.345355406501106 
 1.709923162759449 
 1.3997814480117556
 1.9104888704503833
 1.198399678128354
```